# MS test Manager Training?

Tags: automated-testing, test-management, coded-ui-tests

Using MS Test Manager to manage my test cases and looking for a certification course for Test Manager and automation testing using Coded UI. Any suggestions on finding a company that offers MS certification for Test Manager and VS automated test?

Comment: Why do you need certification for this? I do not think so it requires certification. If you really need to learn, there are bulk of websites about MS test manager.

Answer (score 1):

If your company has a subscription to PluralSight I would recommend them for some of your initial training.
Microsoft offers several certification programs here are a few:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/mcsd-application-lifecycle-management.aspx